# trying to place license badge within readme.md using node.js but getting error argument is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I hope I can explain this right. First, thank you for trying to help a noobie. I am indeed in need of your smart brains.

**Purpose:** Trying to create a readme.md generator using node.js
**Problem:** I keep getting an argument is not defined. I think the problem is that I can't target an object within an array from another js file.

**Picture of the error:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S4fR.png)

**I also have added part of the code below:**

```js
//markdown.js file 

function renderLicenseBadge(license) {
  let licenseType = license.license; // i think this is problem #1
  let yourLicense = ''
  if(licenseType === 'MIT') {
    yourLicense = `![License: MIT](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-MIT-yellow.svg)`
  } else if (licenseType === 'GPLv3') {
    yourLicense = `![GPLv3 license](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-GPLv3-blue.svg)`
  } else if (licenseType === 'GPL') {
    yourLicense = `![GPL license](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-GPL-blue.svg)`
  } else {
    license.license = "N/A"
  }
  return yourLicense;
};

function generateMarkdown(data) {

## license 
return `# ${data.title}
renderLicenseBadge(license) //possible problem #2?
'
}

//index.js file

  const questions =  [
            type: 'checkbox', 
            name: 'license',
            choices: ["MIT", "GPLv3", "GPL"],
            message: 'Pick your License.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `generateMarkdown` function, you need proper syntax when you interpolate the response from `renderLicenseBadge` function. Also, ## license needs to be inside of the template literal

```
function generateMarkdown(data) {


return `# ${data.title}
## license 
${renderLicenseBadge(license)} //possible problem #2?
'
}
```

Then, make sure you are sending in the right data.

- Does the variable license exist already in the `generateMarkdown` function?
- If not, how do I access it through the data argument?

  - ex: 'data.license'? etc...
    Once you send in the right data to the `renderLicenseBadge` function there should be no need to do `license.license`, unless it is an object.

I suggest using `console.log(data)` -- in `generateMarkdown` -- and `console.log(license)` -- in `renderLicenseBadge` -- to keep track of the data types and structures you are sending to each function.

Also, you can `return yourLicense` inside each if else code block.

I hope this helped.